# Smooth removal effect

Tags: javascript, css

I created a photo filter, but I couldn't get a soft removal effect.

I have done the desired effect in method 1 (line 13), but the problem is that there are voids in the places of the hidden elements, and if i write : `display: none;` the effect will be gone.

Here is the link to see what i did:

https://codepen.io/someone_49/pen/mdpWOWY?editors=0010

Here is the link to see  what I'm trying to get at here :

https://ivkovic.me/themes/pluton/#portfolio

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want the animation effect to be - at what point would the remaining items 'move' in to replace the hiding ones? Is it when the hiding ones have completely disappeared or is it gradual - bearing in mind you are operating on a fixed grid.

Comment: I don't quite know how to do this effect; So I put a link to the effect I want to apply. 
"Is it when the hiding ones have completely disappeared or is it gradual".  I want it gradually...
" bearing in mind you are operating on a fixed grid", Does this mean that it is not possible?!

Answer (score 0):

you need to animate the max-width of the elements

Comment: can you explain more...!?